# Do I need a while loop to insert based on conditions?

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement

I want to insert values in a column based on the following conditions. Name of the column to be inserted is project_renewal.

If decimal exists in project_code, insert the numbers after decimals.

```
SELECT substring_index(project_code, '.', -1)
FROM projects where
project_code like '%.%'
```

If no decimal, insert 0.

```
SELECT project_code
FROM projects where
project_code not like '%.%'
```

Order of insert must be the same as the order of reading values from project_code.

Comment: If the value of project_code is 1.2 what do you want to insert: 2 or 20?

Comment: 2. The answer below works for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
 INSERT IGNORE INTO outtable (code)
 SELECT IF (project_code LIKE '%.%'
     , substring_index(project_code, '.', -1)
     , 0)
 FROM projects
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
INSERT INTO tablename(project_renewal)
SELECT trim(trailing '0' from substring_index(project_code, '.', -1)) + 0
FROM projects
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8aDnT4zdN5fkz6QarKS8iT/4).
If you want to update a column in the same table then do it with an UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE projects
SET project_renewal = trim(trailing '0' from substring_index(project_code, '.', -1)) + 0
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8aDnT4zdN5fkz6QarKS8iT/5).